# How to trigger a data refresh in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny application that queries data from SQL into data frames, and then those data frames are referenced from my shinyServer() block. I've been running it only in RStudio thus far, and so whenever I needed new data I'd just restart the application and before the server loads it would grab all new data.

I'd like to transition the app to shiny server, but I'm not sure how I can induce it to get new data periodically. For the sake of the interface I'd like it to be automatic rather than have a user click a button to initiate the loading. Is there an idiomatic solution for this?

EDIT:

I think I found a solution that works for me.

```
shinyServer(function(input,output,session){
    sourceData <- reactive({
        invalidateLater(1000000,session)

        functionThatGetsData()
    })
})
```

Comment: Hi Patrick. I am also building an app that queries and SQL database. I'm having trouble manipulating the data when I use reactiveValues. Can you send me a link to your app / code or is it sensitive? No problem if it is. Thanks. Pete

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for `invalidateLater`. Put this, with the appropriate interval, in the reactive expression that retrieves data from the the database.

Comment: Can this live in an observe() outside shinyServer along with a reactive function? It's the sort of thing I'd want to be available to all users.

Comment: @PatrickMcCarthy you can add `invalidateLater` without `session` in it. also use `<<-` to save it into a global variable for all sessions to use

Answer (score 29):

The smartest would probable be to use `reactivePoll` if you can make a fast query to detect if there is new data. This worked very well for me just today actually.

> `reactivePoll shiny`
>
> ### Reactive polling
>
> #### Description
>
> Used to create a reactive data source, which works by periodically polling a non-reactive data ource.
>
> #### Usage
>
> `reactivePoll(intervalMillis, session, checkFunc, valueFunc)`
>
> #### Arguments
>
> `intervalMillis`
>
> Approximate number of milliseconds to wait between calls to `checkFunc`. his an be either a numeric value, or a function that returns a numeric value.
>
> `session`
>
> The user session to associate this file reader with, or `NULL` if none. If non-null, he reader will automatically stop when the session ends.
>
> `checkFunc` A relatively cheap function whose values over time will be tested for equality; nequality indicates that the underlying value has changed and needs to be invalidated and re-ead using `valueFunc`. See Details.
>
> `valueFunc`
>
> A function that calculates the underlying value. See Details.

Comment: I think this is more appropriate (and elegant) than `invalidateLater` as this is exactly designed for OP's problem.

Comment: Here is a working example for this answer: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/reactive-poll-and-file-reader.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't think either of these answers fully answers OP's question. Specifically

> whenever I needed new data I'd just restart the application and before
>   the server loads it would grab all new data.

which suggests that the *global* object needs to be refreshed. Using reactives inside the server function is not a great answer to that problem bc you have a race condition if multiple users are interacting with the app simultaneously ... all of them will try to update the object concurrently, which may or may not resolve itself well depending on what the update is (this is something I'm actively wrestling with).

One possible solution I've explored is using the flock package to have each user attempt to acquire a lock on a global temp file, and the user successfully acquiring it would be tasked with doing the global update. This directly addresses the race condition. I haven't tested it fully enough to post it as a solution here, maybe someone else can run with that.

Comment: By anychance, would you be able to share a example here.

Comment: Wouldn't putting the reactive in the global.R solve the race issue?

Comment: Hi I still struggle with the difference of updating plots in the global file each day or in the server side. The way I work is that I run daily a data wrangling script which gives output of plots as .RData files. These are saved to Google Drive. Once this is finished I want to refresh them in my Shiny app. I do it like this cause it takes ome time to generate these plots via various functions...and to read in .RData files it goes much quicker