# Setting up data refreshing in Shiny app connected to PostgreSQL

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny, reactive-programming, rpostgresql

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680246/how-to-trigger-a-data-refresh-in-shiny?rq=1) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/GZ9N2NaXxqU) thread and a few others but haven't been able to figure out my solution.

I have built a dashboard using R and Shiny, and said dashboard pulls in data from a Postgres db using the `RPostgreSQL` package. Right now, the code for all the data pulling and analysis is done outside of the `shinyServer` function, and only the displaying part (the `output` and `render` functions) is in the `shinyServer` portion. I'd like to set it up so that the dashboard data is periodically refreshed and the charts are updated. I've looked into `reactivePoll` and `invalidateLater` and understand them, but can't quite figure out how to implement it in my code.

Here's a simplified example `server.R` code:

```
library(RPostgreSQL)

drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, host='host', port='12345', dbname='mydb',
                 user='me', password='mypass')

myQuery <- "select * from table"
myTable <- dbGetQuery(con, myQuery)

foo <- nrow(myTable)
bar <- foo * 2

shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session) {
    output$foo <- renderText(foo)
    output$bar <- renderText(bar)

    session$onSessionEnded(function(){
      dbDisconnect(con)
      dbDisconnect(con2)
      dbUnloadDriver(drv)
    })
  }
)
```

Now if I want `foo` to update periodically, that requires me to refresh the `dbGetQuery` command I have too, and I can't figure out how to make them all work together. Do I need to reformat things and put everything inside the `shinyServer` function? I have about 250 lines of code and it feels wrong to throw them all in there, and just putting the data pull part in there could mess with the order of things. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look into `invalidateLater` which you use with a time argument.  We use this to fresh plots automatically.

Comment: Did the solution from @Thomas K worked for your problem? I have the same issue and would be glad about some working code example. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Blind0ne This question is from over two years ago so to be honest I really don't remember any details, but I marked it as being correct so it must have worked at least partially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `reactivePoll` instead of `invalidateLater`, because it will only re-fetch the whole data in case there is new data.

There is however no way around putting the code to fetch the data inside `shinyServer`, since your subsequent calculations depend on the (reactive) data.

**Disclaimer**: I have no experience with SQL whatsoever, and I couldn't test my code due to the lack of a suitable database, but from my understanding of `shiny` the following code should work.

```
library(RPostgreSQL)

drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, host='host', port='12345', dbname='mydb',
                 user='me', password='mypass')

check_for_update <- function() {
  dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM table") # edit this part in case
  # the syntax is wrong. the goal is to create an identifier which changes
  # when the underlying data changes
}
get_data <- function() {
  dbGetQuery(con, "select * from table")
}
close_connection <- function() {
  dbDisconnect(con)
  dbUnloadDriver(drv)
}

shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session) {
    # checks for new data every 10 seconds
    data <- reactivePoll(10000, session,
                         checkFunc = check_for_update,
                         valueFunc = get_data)

    # the outputs will only be refreshed in case the data changed
    output$foo <- renderText({
      nrow(data())
    })
    output$bar <- renderText({
      bar <- data() * 2
    })

    session$onSessionEnded(close_connection)
  }
)
```

Depending on the structure of your app it could be helpful to wrap the calculations into a separate `reactive`, which you can reuse in several places.

Some notes on code execution with shinyApps can be found in this [tutorial](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson5/#execution).

If you are running into any issues, please leave a comment and I will try to update my post accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I feel like your code would work, but what I'm concerned about is how it will affect the calculations I do on the data outside of the shinyServer, if I refresh it on the inside. I edited my example to include a line for "bar" to make it better. In this case, the data gets refreshed inside the function, but the calculation that gives us the value for bar only happens once outside it. So would I have to move everything inside and have it run every time the data is refreshed?

Comment: @NeonBlueHair I think there is no way around pulling the calculations into `shinyServer`. I don't know what you are doing within your "calculations", but obviously you need to rerun any transformations done on the data if the data itself changes.